# Solr Special boosting function

Tags: solr

The document that i am indexing contain a field with a string that is the document type of the document. For instance, "Technical Note", "Synopsis", "Working Papers" and so one

I wonder if it is possible to write a boosting that help rank the results by the importance of the document type.

In other words,

"Technical Note" - > 0.5
"Synopsis" -> 0.3
"Working Papers" -> 0.2

My idea is to make sure that working papers appears before synopsis for instances.

Is there a way to right this kind of boosting function either search time or index time.

Best,

Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply have :

```
defType=dismax 
bq=type:tec^1 type:syn^2 type:wor^3
```

this will boost your results. Do it on search time only. No need to add value on index time (other than the type of document of course! :) )

You can perform a query that you want in order to retrieve only the records you want as normaly q, qf.... etc.

Links

- [boosting doc](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ)
- [Dismax parser doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser)

Comment: Thank you. Although it sounds like there is no notation to do that with the dismax query parser ? Or what you wrote is applicable to it ?

Comment: Actually i am not sure to fully understand how the all thing would play out. Basic the q parameter is supposed to contain what my user as typed as keyword. Now where exactly does what you wrote into play ? I would have to add it to my solrconfig by the way, once added, will it combine the q parameter as sent by my user with what you wrote? What would be the semantic of it ? Every time you search for anything, also search for tec, syn and wor and give the following boost when you find them ?

Comment: this is a dismax query, nothing else should be added in your case. :)

Comment: I have updated the dismax query in order to be understood. Sorry for mistake

Comment: It seems that the Bq mess with my mm parameter now. are the term found in bq counter in the mm parameter ? Meaning i would need to increase my mm if i always expect to find the bq term in each document ?

Comment: MaatDeamon please can you open another question for this with query, error and desired result please. give me the reference by chat, I will try to help you.

Comment: I will do that, in the mean time could you tell me how can make sure that type:"working Paper" is taken as a whole, as a phrase rather than split into words. Also would that help given that the field is actually analyzed. I don't have full control over the indexation strategy yet.